# Curious to understanding a word formation

Tags: morphology

I am currently studying English language acquisition and an early elementary grade leveled subject's assessment results. The subject was asked to repeat a series of complex sentences. One of the sentences read:

**My friend likes to eat ice cream when it's very hot out.**

The subject responded:

**My friend likes to eat ice cream when it's really hot outside.**

I'm curious to know which type of morpholocical word formation would changing the word **out** to **outside** fall under? Derivational or compounding?

Also, what about replacing the word **very** with **really** even though they both never change their grammatical category? Would this be a simple substitution?

Any input would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why morphological formation is relevant. Just as with *very* and *really*, the subject has substituted another word of similar meaning: it just happens that *outside* contains the same morpheme as *out*.

[I don't know whether or not it is relevant that *out* in this sense is rather restricted in its use: it can follow a verb of being, going or putting (*when I was out*, *I'm going out*), or an adjective of weather (*it's cold out*, *it was wet out*) but not very much else. So the subject has substituted a possibly problematic word by a more straightforward one.]

Comment: This clears up any question. I will refer to both examples as substitution. Your response is greatly appreciated.